# VF Component autocomplete error for more then 50000 record

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, salesforce, visualforce

I have VF page Component in which I am using jQuery AutoComplete which now gives me error as I have more than 50000 records.

PS: I can't make page read-only where this component is used, bcoz its stop me from doing DML statement.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a [`LIMIT` clause](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_limit.htm) to your SOQL queries to keep your row consumption below 50,000. For an autocomplete use case, you probably want to be returning a couple of order of magnitude fewer records to the browser. Querying that many records will limit performance and responsiveness.

Comment: Thanks Dev ,  this auto complete is for search client record on the bases of name of mobile number we can't used limit bcoz there are more then 50000 record of it, and if I out limit rest of the client not appear in auto complete,

Comment: Then you'll need to change how your autocomplete works so that you filter in SOQL instead of browser-side JavaScript. The strategy it sounds like you are using, retrieving all records and filtering in browser, will not work.

Comment: Yes absolutely I think about, I know I am become a bit greedy here, do you know the best way to perform this action. Thanks Dav 